# Real Time Database on Android with Google Maps

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps

we have a android project that needs the following objectives:

*we also have a web application for this app that needs to communicate with the same database as the android application

what I have done so far:

1. a view of a map with a pinpoint on my current Location
2. mysql db containing information (including latitude and longtitude position)
3. registration and login

Real Time Database Objectives:

1. state that people are online or offline(updating a database).

Google Map Objectives:

1. When I press a button, the map will show other users who are online within a given radius so basically I need to view online people who are near me
2. Send a message to them [2 ways]

2.1  I send them a message by clicking their icon

2.2  I send everyone[online people within the radius] the message

Questions:

1. 1. I am currently using php mysql for login/register. Can I use this for a real time database or is there any other way?
2. is Firebase somehow similar to a hosting site?

if there are other needed information needed, pls inform me, I may not have included information that could help with my questions :)
ill update my question too if I have more questions.

thank you.

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. It can be done using PHP and MySQL but I would actually not roll my own back end on this (using php/mysql/node or what ever) but rather get something like firebase or some other hosted and scalable database/api solution. Then you don't need to manage the hosting and usually get a lot of that functionality by default.

Answer (score 1):

I think for your requirements its is more appropriate to use Firebase as it fulfills all your expectations and provides additional features.

Comment: it seems that Firebase only allows email and password for registration, it doesnt allow custom registration fields. can I also used SharedPreferences here just in case a user can login?

Comment: i do not quite understand how to insert profile values ex. name address bday to the firebase db after logging in, can you provide an example?

Comment: You can do it....It is very simple...In the documentation it is clearly specified how to enter values into real time database....https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

Comment: does Firebase handle online or offline users?                                                            * i apologize for asking so many questions. I am new to firebase

Comment: it automatically does that?

Comment: what r u talking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124962/discussion-between-dr-doom-and-raasesh).

Comment: sir, can I ask for help especially with geofire

Comment: i was able to successfully add my current location to firebase however i do not understand the structure. there is the child which is the name of the location then under it has g and l. I understand the "l" contains the coordinates but I dont get what g stands for

Comment: sir please reply :(

Comment: I dont understand how SFVehicles is able to pinpoint all the markers that are within the criteria

Comment: sir I need your help with geoquery i do not know where to add my Geoquery. my app doesnt show the map anymore after adding the geoquery